# Unable to to ingest Google Ads supported objects to AWS S3 using AWS AppFlow

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, amazon-appflow

I'm trying to use AWS AppFlow to ingest Google Ads [supported objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/connectors-google-ads.html#:%7E:text=Supported%20destinations.-,Supported%20objects,-When%20you%20create) to AWS S3. Though i have successfully created connections using GoogleAds Connector I'm unable to ingest the data to S3.

Steps followed from AWS console: 
**Step 1**: Name of the flow was provided.
**Step 2:** Configure Source and Destination. Recently created Google Ads Connection was chosen for source and AWS S3 bucket for destination. Flow Trigger is set to ‘Run on Demand’
([Step2 Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zBeJ.png) )
**Step 3:** Map Data Fields: This page throws the error. ([Step3 Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTF1k.png))

I have followed all the steps as it is from [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/connectors-google-ads.html) 
**Error Message:**

> An error occurred while retrieving fields Error while communicating to
> connector: The request failed because the service Source
> Customconnector returned the following error: Details: **GoogleAds
> metadata response can not be null or empty, ErrorCode: ServerError.**

---

I also tried changing the mapping method and chose to upload a mapping csv file but even it failed with the error "*Couldn't parse rows from the file*."

---

Alternatively when trying to retrieve the campaign object from the [python script](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/examples/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py) it returns the desired output.

Any leads around this will be appreciated.
(Also this is my first post on stack overflow :P)

Comment: Hey Aditya, I have same issue for the last 3 weeks, not sure if this a new issue that came recently or this is something that only us dealing with. My Ads manager generated a developer token and I am using google web app console application from my account to connect to the Ads and read data. I am able to connect, but next page of the Appflow shows same error as yours. Can you share the python code from start to end, I want to try to using it to check if this is working at all with my credentials?

Comment: @pan1ka the link to python script is attached in the question.

Comment: @pan1ka Quick Question: Does your google ads account contain any active campaigns or ads?(I have inactive campaigns in my Ads account, so just checking if we have something In common.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after one month of back and forth with AWS Support team AWS finally added support for Google Ads v11 API version. So after creating the flow with newly modified connection I was able to run the flow and ingest campaign data successfully!